# JavaScript error in placing markers on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-markers

I've had a very frustrating error that's closer to resolution but not quite there. I'm trying to place markers on a Google Map based on lat, long coordinates storied in a Django model.

Thanks to some insight, it looks like AJAX, which I'm not very familiar with, is the way to get these coordinates from the model and then using this to place the markers on the map. In looking at the source code from the result, the coordinates are being retrieved but an error is resulting via Firebug:

```
syntax error
[Break On This Error]   

function loadMarkers(stories):

/report/all/ (line 1172, col 29)
```

Any insight into what may be causing this and what a possible solution might be would be welcome. Just as reference, this is in development mode and all the coordinates are in the same place, which may be too many. The map is no longer displaying with the "loadMarkers" function.

Code follows:

```
<script>
function mainGeo()
    {
         if (navigator.geolocation) 
            {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( mainMap, error, {maximumAge: 30000, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true} );
        }
        else
        {
              alert("Sorry, but it looks like your browser does not support geolocation.");
        }
    }




var map;



 function mainMap(position)
 {
       // Define the coordinates as a Google Maps LatLng Object
       var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

       // Prepare the map options
       var mapOptions =
      {
                  zoom: 15,
                  center: coords,
                  mapTypeControl: false,
                  navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // Create the map, and place it in the map_canvas div
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        // Place the initial marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: coords,
                  map: map,
                  title: "Your current location!"
        });
    }


function error() {
               alert("You have refused to display your location. You will not be able to submit stories.");
        }

mainGeo();

var stories = [{% for story in stories %}
                {{story.latitude}},{{story.latitude}}, {% endfor %}];


    loadMarkers(stories);

function loadMarkers(stories):
for (var s in stories) {
    var story = story[s];
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(story[s]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map: map});
}
```

Edit: Revamped code but retrieves the same error

```
var stories = [{% for story in stories %}
                ({{story.latitude}},{{story.longitude}}) {% endfor %}];


    loadMarkers(stories);

function loadMarkers(stories):
    for (var s in stories) {
        var story = story[s]
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(story.latitude, story.longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map: map});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's stored in story and stories, but when making `var point`, `LatLng`s need to be constructed with two arguments, like (number1, number2), or (string1, string2) where the strings represent numbers.

If story[s] is a single string, say "39.39, 20.21" you simply need to `split(",")` to obtain two number-strings.

```
    myString = "40.7, -70.4";
    myStringValues = myString.split(",");
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(myStringValues[0], myStringValues[1]);
```

Also latitude is repeated in `var stories`, shouldn't one be longitude?

Comment: Change Good catch. Revised code above. Still results in the same error. The "stories" var has the lat and long separated by a comma for each individual object.